# Reloading comboBox using resetText()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

```
    private void ReloadForm()
    {
        comboBox4.ResetText();
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string layers = textBox1.Text;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("xml/" + layers + ".xml", FileMode.Create);

        XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(fs);

        w.WriteStartDocument();
        w.WriteStartElement("layers");

        // Write a product.
        w.WriteStartElement("layer");
        w.WriteAttributeString("id", "1");
        w.WriteElementString("layerName", layers);
        w.WriteEndElement();

        w.WriteEndDocument();
        w.Flush();
        fs.Close();
        ReloadForm();
    }
public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Put XML name files in comboBox4
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"xml\", "*");
            foreach (string file in filePaths)
            {
                string mypath = file;
                string[] directories = mypath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
                foreach (string dir in directories){
                        comboBox4.Items.Add(dir);
                }
            }
        }
```

The code above create XML files on click and I got seperate code that display the name of each XML file. 
I've tried to use `void ReloadForm()` to refresh comboBox4 text, but It failed..

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: you can simply add your value to the combo box by `Items.Add` or `Binding`

Comment: @AsfK I used Items.Add, yet the items doesn't appear right away.. I need to exit my program and restart it.

Comment: try `Refresh` after your adding

Comment: @AsfK doesn't works either, I added my other code to my question.

Comment: :( As I know, it's should work. can you debug your app please and verify your `dir` variable really contain data...

Comment: @AsfK Well, it does have bug (which I wanted to fix later) that it shows me file extenstion then it shows me file name + file extenstion, and its looping like that. I'm didn't thought that might be the problem.

Comment: :) now you can enjoy. have fun!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64117/discussion-between-exclusiv3-and-asfk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `Form3` constructor to this

```
public Form3()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ReloadComboBox4();
}
```

and rename your `ReloadForm()` to `ReloadComboBox4` and change it to this

```
private void ReloadComboBox4()
{
    comboBox4.Items.Clear()
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"xml\", "*");
    foreach (string file in filePaths)
    {
        string mypath = file;
        string[] directories = mypath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
        foreach (string dir in directories)
        {
            comboBox4.Items.Add(dir);
        }
    }
}
```